# Show whitespace characters in monospace environments

Tags: verbatim, typewriter

I need to render an ASCII file for printing in a way that removes ambiguity if (very unlikely) one decides to type it in and validate the signatures.

Essentially, I need a monospace typesetter that would typeset a 'blank space' symbol for space, a CR/LF symbol (and proceed to the next line for readability) whenever a CR/LF is encountered, etc., making it obvious if there are any trailing whitespaces before the CR/LF, if there is a  character present, etc.

Is there a font that already accomplishes that goal? *nix utility? TeX module/package/derived system?

Is this even the proper SE site for this kind of questions? Would you think I'd have better luck at SuperUser? StackOverflow?

Comment: the standard `verbatim*` environment does spaces (but not by default end of line) although could easily be added

Comment: Have you considered the `a2ps` *nix utility. As far as I remember it is configurable to fulfill your needs.

Comment: I've looked at a2ps - I haven't seen a good example on how that could be done - do you know of a good documentation for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?  In this case, I made `@` active to denote the end of the verbatim each line, so that it could both detect prior spaces, as well as typeset a `<cr>` to signify the end of line. (See **ADDENDUM** for update)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\def\rlwd{.5pt}
\begin{document}
\catcode`@=\active
\def@{<cr>}
\def\tmp{\setbox2=\hbox{0}%
  \def\ {\makebox[\wd2]{\rule{\rlwd}{2pt}\rule{3pt}{\rlwd}\rule{\rlwd}{2pt}}}%
}
\begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
This is a test         @
more test      @
The end@
\end{verbnobox}
\catcode`@=12
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one did not like the confusion of having the `<cr>` in the same font as the `verbatim`, one could alter it thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,xcolor}
\def\rlwd{.5pt}
\begin{document}
\catcode`@=\active
\def@{\textcolor{red}{{\tiny\rmfamily\bfseries$<$cr$>$}}}
\def\tmp{\setbox2=\hbox{0}%
  \def\ {\makebox[\wd2]{\rule{\rlwd}{2pt}\rule{3pt}{\rlwd}\rule{\rlwd}{2pt}}}%
}
\begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
This is a test         @
more test      @
The end@
\end{verbnobox}
\catcode`@=12
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Since this answer was originally provided I have learned that `verbatim` environment and even the `\verb` macro have star variants (e.g., `verbatim*`) which provide the visible space glyph.  Thus, no extra packages are actually needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\catcode`@=\active
\def@{<cr>}
\begin{verbatim*}
This is a test         @
more test      @
The end@
\end{verbatim*}
\catcode`@=12
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some modification to [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) allows you to reformat the end-of-line character (below I've used `\CR`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\CR}{<cr>}

\makeatletter

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=\active
\gdef\FancyVerbGetLine#1^^M{%
  \@nil%
  \FV@CheckEnd{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\FV@EnvironName%            % True if end is found
    \ifx\@tempb\FV@@@CheckEnd\else\FV@BadEndError\fi%
    \let\next\FV@EndScanning%
  \else%
    \def\FV@Line{#1\CR}%
    \def\next{\FV@PreProcessLine\FV@GetLine}%
  \fi%
  \next}%
\endgroup

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[showspaces=true]
This is a test         @
more test      @
The end@
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

The definition of `\FancyVerbGetLine` was taken directly from [`fancyvrb.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.dtx) and modified to insert `\CR` as part of the definition of `\FV@line`.